# Change decimal seperator locale in Android string resource

Tags: java, android, string, kotlin, format

I want to display some coördinates in my Android app.
I receive two double values (`lat` and `long` in decimal degrees notation) from my backend.

Example data:

```
var lat : Double = 52.5027
var long : Double = 5.41982
```

Now i fill my textView in my class file:

```
tvLat.text = getString(R.string.gps_format, lat)
tvLong.text = getString(R.string.gps_format, lat)
```

and my xml resource file contains this:

```
<string name="gps_format">%,.5f&#176;</string>
```

It displays:

```
52,50270°
5,41982°
```

As I live in the Netherlands it is formatted accordingly.

See https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter

> **Number Localization Algorithm**
>
> 1. ...
> 2. If a decimal separator is present, a locale-specific decimal separator is substituted.

We typically use a `,` as a `decimal separator`, and `.` as a `group separator` in  the Netherlands.

**Question:**

- Is there an international standard for the notation of coördinates in decimal degrees which requires the decimal seperator to be `.`?
- If there is, or I just want to, how do I achieve this without changing my locale or formatting for the entire app?

Desired output:

```
52.50270°
5.41982°
```

I have not found a way yet for the XML, so my guess is that it will have to be done with code. I've looked into the `setDecimalSeparator` method, but I can't get any working solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've found something which could be called a dirty solution.

```
tvLat.text =
    getString(R.string.gps_format,
        DecimalFormat(
            "0.00000",
            DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault())
                .apply { decimalSeparator = '.' }
        ).format(lat).toString()
    )
```

Along with a change in my resource file

```
<string name="gps_format">%s&#176;</string>
```

New output:

```
52.50270°
5.41982°
```

I would like to have the format in my string resource though.
Anyone has suggestions?